# Bash script to save each line of a file to a series of files?

Tags: bash

I've got a file that has a json string on each line of the file

I'd like to save each line of that file to a separate json file, and optionally run a command on each line before it's saved to a file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following will do this

```
save_each_line_of_file_to_a_file.sh /tmp/dump.json
```

#### save_each_line_of_file_to_a_file.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function show_help()
{
  IT="
usage: FILE {OUTPUT_PREFIX} {OUTPUT_POSTFIX} ${OUTPUT_FOLDER}

e.g. 

/tmp/myfile           -> generates files in pwd, 1,2,3,4, etc for each line
/tmp/myfile OUT json  -> generates files in pwd, OUT1.json,OUT2.json,OUT3.json,OUT4.json, etc for each line
"

  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  show_help
fi

OUTPUT_PREFIX=${2:-}
OUTPUT_POSTFIX=${3:-}
OUTPUT_FOLDER=${4:-}
EXTRA_CMD=${5:-}

FILE=${1:-/dev/stdin}

INDEX=1
while read line
do
  OUTPUT_FILENAME="${OUTPUT_FOLDER}${OUTPUT_PREFIX}$INDEX${OUTPUT_POSTFIX}"
  echo $OUTPUT_FILENAME
  INDEX=$((INDEX+1))

if [ -z "$EXTRA_CMD" ]
then
  echo $line > $OUTPUT_FILENAME
else
  echo $line | $EXTRA_CMD > $OUTPUT_FILENAME
fi
done < "$FILE"


      echo "$IT"
      exit
    }

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  show_help
fi

OUTPUT_PREFIX=${2:-}
OUTPUT_POSTFIX=${3:-}
OUTPUT_FOLDER=${4:-}
EXTRA_CMD=${5:-}

FILE=${1:-/dev/stdin}

INDEX=1
while read line
do
  OUTPUT_FILENAME="${OUTPUT_FOLDER}${OUTPUT_PREFIX}$INDEX${OUTPUT_POSTFIX}"
  echo $OUTPUT_FILENAME
  INDEX=$((INDEX+1))

if [ -z "$EXTRA_CMD" ]
then
  echo $line > $OUTPUT_FILENAME
else
  echo $line | $EXTRA_CMD > $OUTPUT_FILENAME
fi
done < "$FILE"
```

Comment: Problems: always use `read -r` (unless you explicitly don't want in some rare cases). 2.) Position based script arguments are confusing. Consider to use `getopt`. 3.) imagine what happens if your `JSON` line will contain something like: `{"key": "value\" * \"here"}` 4.) **Many other problems.** While me understand posting questions and answers to (to your own question), but **same time**? At least, would be nice to post "correct" (problem free) script/answer.

Comment: Really? This is better than what I found googling - ie nothing. At least this is a starting point. If you want to improve it, please do and just supply a better answer. Thanks!